# How to add dictionary inside of an another dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been trying to add one of my dictionaries into another one. I did do that using the code below, but when I update one of the values, all off the values with the same name is also updated. How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
test_dict = {'count': 0}

D = {'emp1': {'name': test_dict, 'job': 'Mgr'},
     'emp2': {'name': test_dict, 'job': 'Dev'},
     'emp3': {'name': test_dict, 'job': 'Dev'}}

D['emp1']['name']['count'] += 1

print(D)
```

The output is this

{'emp1': {'name': {'count': 1}, 'job': 'Mgr'}, 'emp2': {'name': {'count': 1}, 'job': 'Dev'}, 'emp3': {'name': {'count': 1}, 'job': 'Dev'}}

when I should have this. How can I fix it?

{'emp1': {'name': {'count': 1}, 'job': 'Mgr'}, 'emp2': {'name': {'count': 0}, 'job': 'Dev'}, 'emp3': {'name': {'count': 0}, 'job': 'Dev'}}

Answer (score 3):

In fact in your `D` dictionary the emp1, emp2 and emp3 all point to the same reference (a same object in memory).
That's the reason why, when you modify one of your inner dicts, you see the others as modified (in reality this is always the same and unique dict).
You have to make copies of the initial `test_dict`.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

D = {'emp1': {'name': deepcopy(test_dict), 'job': 'Mgr'},
     'emp2': {'name': deepcopy(test_dict), 'job': 'Dev'},
     'emp3': {'name': deepcopy(test_dict), 'job': 'Dev'}}
```

Comment: The `copy` module is not external, it's part of the Python core modules.

Comment: I prefer to use `deepcopy()` instead of `copy()`.
On this example the result will be identical.
But if `test_dict` was a highly nested dict there would be a risk to still have shared references.
A simple `copy()` operates a shallow-copy, meaning that children (referenced) objects
 would not be copies and the copied dict would still reference some part of the initial dict.
By using `deepcopy()` you ensure that **all** inner objects are copied.

Answer (score 2):

This happen because each emp keys share the same dictionary object (same id). You must make a copy of it for each emp just using `copy()`

```
test_dict = {'count': 0}


D = {'emp1': {'name': test_dict.copy(), 'job': 'Mgr'},
     'emp2': {'name': test_dict.copy(), 'job': 'Dev'},
     'emp3': {'name': test_dict.copy(), 'job': 'Dev'}}

D['emp1']['name']['count'] += 1

print(D)
```

Output:

```
{'emp1': {'name': {'count': 1}, 'job': 'Mgr'}, 'emp2': {'name': {'count': 0}, 'job': 'Dev'}, 'emp3': {'name': {'count': 0}, 'job': 'Dev'}}
```